# Why SSRS reports works in development but not in Production

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, parameters, parameter-sniffing

I have a SELECT statement (NOT a Stored Procedure) that I am using to create a report in SSRS (Visual Studio 2010).

Parameter @ClassCode is the one that causing a trouble. But in Development it works fine, but when I deploy it to Production it renders forever.

I am assuming it a Parameter Sniffing, and I read about how to fix it inside the Stored Procedure. But I dont have a SP, I am using a SELECT statement.

What would be the workaround for SELECT statement?
And what is the difference between environments? Production is much much more powerful. 
My query below:

```
;WITH cte1
AS
(
    SELECT  QuoteID,
             AccidentDate,
            PolicyNumber,
            SUM(PaidLosses) as PaidLosses
    FROM    tblLossesPlazaCommercialAuto
    WHERE   InsuredState IN  (@State)  AND AccidentDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate AND TransactionDate <= @EndDate AND  Coverage = 'VehicleComprehensive'
    GROUP BY QuoteID,
            AccidentDate,
            PolicyNumber
),
cte3
AS
(
SELECT      
            cte1.Quoteid,
            cte1.PolicyNumber,
            cte1.AccidentDate,
            cc.TransactionEffectiveDate,
            cc.ClassCode,
                CASE
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte1.QuoteID, cte1.PolicyNumber,cc.AccidentDate ORDER BY (SELECT 0))=1 THEN cte1.PaidLosses 
                ELSE 0
            END  as PaidLosses--,
FROM        cte1 inner join tblClassCodesPlazaCommercial cc 
                        on cte1.PolicyNumber=cc.PolicyNumber 
                        AND cte1.AccidentDate=cc.AccidentDate
            AND cc.AccidentDate IS NOT NULL
    /* This is the one that gives me problem */
            WHERE  cc.ClassCode   IN (@ClassCode)
) 
SELECT  SUM(PaidLosses) as PaidLosses, c.YearNum, c.MonthNum
FROM    cte3 RIGHT JOIN tblCalendar  c ON c.YearNum = YEAR(cte3.AccidentDate) AND c.MonthNum = MONTH(cte3.AccidentDate)
WHERE   c.YearNum <>2017
GROUP BY  c.YearNum, c.MonthNum
ORDER BY  c.YearNum, c.MonthNum
```

Comment: Have you tried running the query in SSMS against the dev and prod environments? Do you see the same performance difference? If so you can look at the query plan...

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have two table scans. I think this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Used Tuning Advisor to see what indexes and statistics needed the workload. After creating those - everything works fine.